# Return values to jQuery from ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wonder how I should handle error and return values on server side when making ajax request with jQuery.

I'm doing a database insert from an ajax request, and I want to return the database insert primary key ID to jQuery. But if nothing was inserted, or if some validation failed I want to return an error. This is how I usually do it:

Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "test.php",
    data: {stuff: stuff, stuff2: stuff2},
    success: function(response){
        switch( parseInt(response) ) {
            // Display different messages depending on return value
        }
    },
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

Serverside:

```
if (some validation) { echo 1; exit; }
if (other validation) { echo 2; exit; }
if (everything went okay) { echo database id; exit; }
```

You don't need to be a genius to understand that this is bad coding. What is the best practice in this scenario? Should I return a JSON string?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems fine to me, as long you know what you're returning and you're in control !

Comment: For returning just a simple id, plain text is fine. there's a typo in your php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON works well. Have a JSON object with either a "result" key or an "error" key.

```
{result: [value]} or {error: [message]}
```

In your jQuery callback check for the keys in your response object

```
if("result" in response} {
    // success
} else {
    // error
    alert( (response.error || "ERROR") );
}
```

**edit** You can of course get as complex as you need. "Type", "Value", "Message" are some common JSON keys.

```
{
    type: [SUCCESS|WARNING|ERROR]
    value: [expected return value|array of warnings|array of errors]
    message: [some custom message to display to the user]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling an error in the `success` callback is sufficiently surprising that other people may have a hard time maintaining your code. If you are following REST principles, then you will want to return a 4xx status code in your response from the server. For example, return `400 Bad Request` for a generic error, return `409 Conflict` if there is some sort of resource conflict, etc. Then, handle the error response in the `error` function callback option passed to `ajax.`

If you want more details that just an [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1), you can *also* return a JSON object (or even just a plain text string) that explains the problem in greater detail. In my REST APIs, I typically just return a plain text description of the error in the response body, then set the response Content-Type to `"text/plain"`.